# Python pyplot legend scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got 5 classes and some features that I want to plot. This is the code

```
x_pts = X_test.iloc[:,col_1]
y_pts = X_test.iloc[:,col_2]
color_seq = y_test
plt.scatter(x_pts, y_pts, c=color_seq, cmap='viridis')
plt.xlabel(X_test.columns[col_1])
plt.ylabel(X_test.columns[col_2])
plt.show()
```

and this results in the following image

[image: plot]

I now want a legend for each color (e.g. yellow = 'class a' , blue = 'class b', ...)
The only documentation I can find is of people plotting each color differently, which is quite hard in my specific case. Isn't there a simple way to display a legend [like the example here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-with-legend-py)

Comment: The example you link to shows how to do it using `scatter.legend_elements()` right?  What happens if you try it? In how far is this not what you want?

Comment: Since you are using a color map, it seems there aren't hard breakpoints in the colors. you may want to use a [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it comes very close but the legend then displays simply the numbers of 1 to 5, I'd like to give it strings

Comment: Ok, then define a list of labels.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
x = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
y = [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 8]
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
colors = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
scatter = plt.scatter(x, y,c=colors, cmap='viridis')
plt.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I got really close but then got this error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`